# .NET components for real-time shipping quotes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, components

When developing custom ecommerce solutions, which "off the shelf" .NET based shipping components have you had luck with?

It absolutely must give real-time shipping quotes and be easily integrated into a ASP.NET website.  Ideally I'd like it to support most of the common US domestic shipping companies (UPS, FedEx, USPS, etc.).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's [.net SHIP](http://www.dotnetship.com/), which I haven't used, but I have used their .net CHARGE product with success.

Comment: Yeah, but no demo to try. I sent 3 emails to them and have been ignored. The web site look amateurish. Taken together, I'll pass. Any others?

Answer (score 0):

UPS has web services available which are easy to expose via .NET proxies, etc. That's what we have used.  For other shippers like DHL, FedEx, and USPS, we have our own estimates based on our own shipping and handling costs.

Typically you're going to want to pad their costs with your own costs.